# Displaying string variable (metatitle) in popup Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a popup Google chrome extension and am having some difficulty displaying a string variable in the extension popup.

I work in marketing and am trying to build an extension that provides useful stats about a website like word count, meta tags and keyword frequency. I can do most of the do most of the analysis in browser side JS, but am having some difficulties with the chrome extension JS, such as passing and displaying all the variables in the pop-up.

I am also having some difficulty understanding the JS code that is required to pass variables between background.js file and the popup.js file.

I have not written all the code below, I am modifying an extension from github, which was shared.

In total I want to pull in and display about 40 variables, mostly strings and numbers. Not sure what the best way to do this. Any suggestions would be welcome. Like the best ways to send and receive them all.

Here is my code

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Meta Tags</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Meta Tags</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Property</th>
                    <th>Http-equiv</th>
                    <th class="valueth">Value</th>
                    <th>Charset</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="metaTable"></tbody>
        </table>
        <h3>MetaTitle</h3>
        <p id="metaTitleID">JS Metatitle should display here.</p>
        <p id="metaTitlePrintOut"></p>
        <h4>Analysis of metatitle</h4>
        <p id="metaTitleChecker"></p>
    </body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

**getPageMetas.js**

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
var metaTitle = document.title;
//console.log(metaTitle)
var metaArr = [];
for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
    var name = metas[i].getAttribute("name");
    var property = metas[i].getAttribute("property");
    var httpequiv = metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv");
    var content = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
    var charset = metas[i].getAttribute("charset");

    metaArr.push([name, property, httpequiv, content, charset]);
}

// not sure if data:metaTitle is the correct way to pass variable between JS files
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method:"getMetas",
    metas:metaArr,
    data:metaTitle
});
```

**popup.js
**

```
function getMetas() {
    var message = document.querySelector('#metaTable');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "getPageMetas.js"
    }, function() {
        // If you try it into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            message.innerText = 'There was an error : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
        }
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    var metaTable = document.getElementById('metaTable');
    if (request.method == "getMetas") {
         document.getElementById("metaTitleID").innerHTML = request.metaTitle;
        for (var i=0; i<request.metas.length; i++) {
            metaTable.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+request.metas[i][0]+"</td><td>"+request.metas[i][1]+"</td><td>"+request.metas[i][2]+"</td><td>"+request.metas[i][3]+"</td><td>"+request.metas[i][4]+"</td></tr>";
        }
    }
});



window.onload = getMetas;
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Meta tags - SEO Tool",
    "description": "This extension will list all the meta tags in a webpage",
    "version": "1.0.1",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

**
Summary**

Main difficulty is dynamically displaying a metaTitle in popup.html, currently it does not display. Also just ignore the table in the popup, I am interested in the metaTitleID JS insert displaying.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: It's good that you pasted the code into your question. Can you also upload it to a website like Github? I want to try your code, but I don't feel like copypasting it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will upload it to Github, later this evening in about 8 hours.

Comment: This code should work, although it can be simplified. The problem is that your popup script reads `request.metaTitle` but there's no such property in the message. You can use devtools to debug your code and inspect the actually sent data. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @ThomasMueller hey managed to do it sooner, here is a link to all the code in github.   https://github.com/rmackindata/seo-meta-mate-final

Comment: @rob-mac https://github.com/rmackindata/seo-meta-mate-final leads me to a 404 error page. Is this a private repo? On the other hand, https://github.com/rmackindata/seo-meta-mate is publically accessible, but it's empty.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, sorry it was private, it is public now, let me know if you still cant get access.

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, thanks for taking the time to look at my scripts. Any ideas how I add metaTitle to the message, does 

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
 method:"getMetas",
 metas:metaArr,
 data:metaTitle
});

Actually send a variable to popup.js and is the script correct in collecting and displaying the variable.

Sorry I am pretty new to development

Comment: You send `data` property, so you need to read `request.data` as well.

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, great I will try modifying the script later today and let you know how I get on. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The above code sends the JS variable, however does not receive it correctly.

JS to receive var in popup.js file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      var data1 = request.data1;
            console.log(data1)
            document.getElementById("metaTitle").innerHTML = request.data1;
});
```

Hopefully that helps some one out.